# What is the difference between differentially expressed genes and deregulated genes?

Tags: gene-expression

Can anyone explain clearly what is the difference between differentially expressed genes and deregulated genes?

Comment: have you done some research on your own and if so, why it wasn't satisfactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any gene whose gene expression differs significantly from some reference is considered to be differentially expressed. I think the most common representation of differential expression is the volcano plot, where you're plotting the fold change or log2 fold change against the -log10 p value assigned that gene.

This means a couple of things: One, you need a sufficently large sample size that you can actually *get* statistics, and two, you need a sufficient reference sample which will act as your baseline.

If a gene is degregulated, however, the expression is **aberrant**. In order to characterize aberrant expression you need a *normal* sample or accepted reference sample, and the sample of interest. This might be as simple as tumor vs normal tissue from the same patient.